# Can I effectively choose gnupg recipients by email address?

Tags: gnupg

We have a perl program that generates gpg encrypted files for multiple folks.

Today, we added *dan@example.com*.
When I run the encryption script, it happily encrypts the file for dan@example.com using *jordan@example.com*.  This is presumably because *jordan@example.com* was in my keyring first.

I've tested from the command line, and if I use **gpg -r dan@example.com --encrypt foo.txt**, the friendly client chooses to use the public key for **jordan@example.com**, instead of the more explicit **dan@example.com**.

Of course, if I use key ids it works, but that's not really what we've got here.  Is there a way to tell gnupg to use the more explicit email address without resorting to key ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented in the manual page that comes with gpg. Section "HOW TO SPECIFY A USER ID" you find the option "By exact match on an email address.". So the answer to your question is to use angle braces such as `<dan@example.com>`.

Comment: Thanks for not saying "RTFM n00b!"